# AWS EC2 Server can not access a fileshare over a VPC VPN using the machine name

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, kerberos, sonicwall, amazon-vpc

I have a windows server on EC2 that is connected to my office via VPN.  I'm having an issue connecting to file shares over the VPN.  I'm able to connect if I use the IP address for example if I use \192.168.1.201 I can connect and transfer files between EC2 and my local network.  However when I use \myMachineName  I'm unable to connect.

1) I opened all TCP traffic on AWS  and in my firewall. TCP is open AWS->Local and Local -> AWS.

2)Reverse DNS is setup correctly for both machines and they are on the same domain connected to the same DNS server that is on my local network

3) I'm able to use the machine name when connecting from my local network to AWS \MachineOnAWS  works. I can transfer files back to AWS.

I used wireshark and I get the following error when trying to connect to a local file share using \myMachineName form amazon:

KRB5KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED

Comment: Enabling Kerberos logging is showing me an authentication issue for krbtgt

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution to this problem by making a change to the Active Directory user that was trying to access the resource.  Under Account -> Account Options:  check "Do not require Kerberos preauthentication"